# Setup WiFi Direct(P2P) on two raspberry pi by using wpa_supplicant

Tags: raspberry-pi, p2p, raspberry-pi4, wifi-direct, wpa-supplicant

I want connect two raspberry pi 4B by using p2p. Then i am using wpa_supplicant to set up p2p. However, after i finished set up the wpa_supplicant.conf and run wpa_supplicant sucessful. The wpa_cli still cannot find other raspberry mac address.
Here is my wpa_supplicant at /etc/wpa_supplicant/supplicant.conf
raspberry pi 1:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
device_name=Terminal-1
device_type=1-0050F204-1
driver_param=use_p2p_group_interface=1
p2p_go_intent=1
p2p_go_ht40=1
p2p_listen_reg_class=81
p2p_listen_channel=1
p2p_oper_reg_class=81
p2p_oper_channel=1
country=GB
```

raspberry pi 2

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
device_name=Terminal-1
device_type=1-0050F204-1
driver_param=use_p2p_group_interface=1
p2p_go_intent=15
p2p_go_ht40=1
p2p_listen_reg_class=81
p2p_listen_channel=1
p2p_oper_reg_class=81
p2p_oper_channel=1
country=GB
```

Then I run

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager
sude killall wpa_supplicant
sudo systemctl disabble NetworkManager
```

Then type

```
wpa_supplicant -Bd -iwaln0 -Dnl80211 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant
```

and  show

```
wpa_supplicant v2.9
random: getrandom() support available
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Initializing interface 'wlan0' conf '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-t1.conf' driver 'nl80211' ctrl_interface 'N/A' bridge 'N/A'
Configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-t1.conf' -> '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-t1.conf'
Reading configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-t1.conf'
ctrl_interface='DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant'
update_config=1
device_name='Terminal-1'
driver_param='use_p2p_group_interface=1'
p2p_go_intent=1
p2p_go_ht40=1
p2p_listen_reg_class=81
p2p_listen_channel=1
p2p_oper_reg_class=81
p2p_oper_channel=1
country='GB'
nl80211: Using driver-based roaming
nl80211: TDLS supported
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:6
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Supported vendor command: vendor_id=0x1018 subcmd=1
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface (driver advertised support)
nl80211: Enable multi-channel concurrent (driver advertised support)
nl80211: use P2P_DEVICE support
nl80211: interface wlan0 in phy phy0
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211: Subscribe to mgmt frames with non-AP handle 0xbaa968
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=0104
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=040a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=040b
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=040c
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=040d
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=090a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=090b
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=090c
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=090d
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=0409506f9a09
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=7f506f9a09
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=0409506f9a1a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=0801
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=040e
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=12
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=06
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=0a07
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=0a11
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=0a1a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=1101
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=1102
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=0505
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbaa968 match=0500
rfkill: initial event: idx=0 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=3 linkmode=1 (userspace-control), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
nl80211: driver param='use_p2p_group_interface=1'
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface
Add interface wlan0 to a new radio phy0
nl80211: Regulatory information - country=GB (DFS-ETSI)
nl80211: 2400-2483 @ 40 MHz 20 mBm
nl80211: 5150-5250 @ 80 MHz 23 mBm (no outdoor)
nl80211: 5250-5350 @ 80 MHz 20 mBm (no outdoor) (DFS)
nl80211: 5470-5730 @ 160 MHz 26 mBm (DFS)
nl80211: 5725-5850 @ 80 MHz 23 mBm (no outdoor)
nl80211: 57000-71000 @ 2160 MHz 40 mBm
nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
nl80211: Mode IEEE 802.11g: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472 2484[DISABLED]
nl80211: Mode IEEE 802.11a: 5170[DISABLED] 5180 5190[DISABLED] 5200 5210[DISABLED] 5220 5230[DISABLED] 5240 5260[NO_IR][RADAR] 5280[NO_IR][RADAR] 5300[NO_IR][RADAR] 5320[NO_IR][RADAR] 5500[NO_IR][RADAR] 5520[NO_IR][RADAR]
nl80211: Mode IEEE 802.11b: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472 2484[DISABLED]
wlan0: Own MAC address: e4:5f:01:f8:f7:49
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=4 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=5 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wlan0: RSN: flushing PMKID list in the driver
nl80211: Flush PMKIDs
wlan0: State: DISCONNECTED -> INACTIVE
TDLS: TDLS operation supported by driver
TDLS: Driver uses internal link setup
TDLS: Driver does not support TDLS channel switching
wlan0: WPS: UUID based on MAC address: 04947705-15a4-5157-a24b-0c92f5c27678
ENGINE: Loading builtin engines
ENGINE: Loading builtin engines
EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state DISCONNECTED
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
nl80211: Skip set_supp_port(unauthorized) while not associated
EAPOL: KEY_RX entering state NO_KEY_RECEIVE
EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state INITIALIZE
EAP: EAP entering state DISABLED
wlan0: Added interface wlan0
wlan0: State: INACTIVE -> DISCONNECTED
nl80211: Set wlan0 operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=3 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
nl80211: Create interface iftype 10 (P2P_DEVICE)
nl80211: New P2P Device interface p2p-dev-wlan0 (0x3) created
Initializing interface 'p2p-dev-wlan0' conf '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-t1.conf' driver 'nl80211' ctrl_interface 'DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant' bridge 'N/A'
Configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-t1.conf' -> '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-t1.conf'
Reading configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-t1.conf'
ctrl_interface='DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant'
update_config=1
device_name='Terminal-1'
driver_param='use_p2p_group_interface=1'
p2p_go_intent=1
p2p_go_ht40=1
p2p_listen_reg_class=81
p2p_listen_channel=1
p2p_oper_reg_class=81
p2p_oper_channel=1
country='GB'
nl80211: Using driver-based roaming
nl80211: TDLS supported
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:6
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Supported vendor command: vendor_id=0x1018 subcmd=1
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface (driver advertised support)
nl80211: Enable multi-channel concurrent (driver advertised support)
nl80211: use P2P_DEVICE support
nl80211: interface p2p-dev-wlan0 in phy phy0
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 0 iftype 10 (P2P_DEVICE)
nl80211: Failed to set interface 0 to mode 10: -22 (Invalid argument)
nl80211: Subscribe to mgmt frames with non-AP handle 0xbc4f18
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=0104
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=040a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=040b
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=040c
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=040d
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=090a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=090b
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=090c
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=090d
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=0409506f9a09
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=7f506f9a09
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=0409506f9a1a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=0801
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=040e
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=12
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=06
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=0a07
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=0a11
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=0a1a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=1101
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=1102
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=0505
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0xbc4f18 match=0500
nl80211: Use (wlan0) to initialize P2P Device rfkill
rfkill: initial event: idx=0 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
nl80211: Start P2P Device p2p-dev-wlan0 (0x3): Success
nl80211: driver param='use_p2p_group_interface=1'
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface
Add interface p2p-dev-wlan0 to existing radio phy0
nl80211: Regulatory information - country=GB (DFS-ETSI)
nl80211: 2400-2483 @ 40 MHz 20 mBm
nl80211: 5150-5250 @ 80 MHz 23 mBm (no outdoor)
nl80211: 5250-5350 @ 80 MHz 20 mBm (no outdoor) (DFS)
nl80211: 5470-5730 @ 160 MHz 26 mBm (DFS)
nl80211: 5725-5850 @ 80 MHz 23 mBm (no outdoor)
nl80211: 57000-71000 @ 2160 MHz 40 mBm
nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
nl80211: Mode IEEE 802.11g: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472 2484[DISABLED]
nl80211: Mode IEEE 802.11a: 5170[DISABLED] 5180 5190[DISABLED] 5200 5210[DISABLED] 5220 5230[DISABLED] 5240 5260[NO_IR][RADAR] 5280[NO_IR][RADAR] 5300[NO_IR][RADAR] 5320[NO_IR][RADAR] 5500[NO_IR][RADAR] 5520[NO_IR][RADAR]
nl80211: Mode IEEE 802.11b: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472 2484[DISABLED]
p2p-dev-wlan0: Own MAC address: e6:5f:01:f8:f7:49
p2p-dev-wlan0: RSN: flushing PMKID list in the driver
nl80211: Flush PMKIDs
p2p-dev-wlan0: State: DISCONNECTED -> INACTIVE
p2p-dev-wlan0: WPS: UUID from the first interface: 04947705-15a4-5157-a24b-0c92f5c27678
ENGINE: Loading builtin engines
ENGINE: Loading builtin engines
EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state DISCONNECTED
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
nl80211: Skip set_supp_port(unauthorized) while not associated
EAPOL: KEY_RX entering state NO_KEY_RECEIVE
EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state INITIALIZE
EAP: EAP entering state DISABLED
Using existing control interface directory.
P2P: Add operating class 81
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=13): 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d
P2P: Add operating class 115
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Add operating class 116
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 24 2c
P2P: Add operating class 117
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 28 30
P2P: Add operating class 128
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Add operating class 130
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Own listen channel: 81:1
P2P: Configured operating channel: 81:1
P2P: initialized
P2P: channels: 81:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 115:36,40,44,48 116:36,44 117:40,48 128:36,40,44,48 130:36,40,44,48
P2P: cli_channels:
p2p-dev-wlan0: Added interface p2p-dev-wlan0
p2p-dev-wlan0: State: INACTIVE -> DISCONNECTED
nl80211: Set p2p-dev-wlan0 operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=0 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
p2p-dev-wlan0: Determining shared radio frequencies (max len 2)
p2p-dev-wlan0: Shared frequencies (len=0): completed iteration
P2P: Add operating class 81
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=13): 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d
P2P: Add operating class 115
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Add operating class 116
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 24 2c
P2P: Add operating class 117
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 28 30
P2P: Add operating class 128
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Add operating class 130
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Update channel list
P2P: channels: 81:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 115:36,40,44,48 116:36,44 117:40,48 128:36,40,44,48 130:36,40,44,48
P2P: cli_channels:
Daemonize..
```

I'm not sure is that success.
and the iw dev is show

```
phy#0
    Unnamed/non-netdev interface
        wdev 0x3
        addr e6:5f:01:f8:f7:49
        type P2P-device
        txpower 31.00 dBm
    Interface wlan0
        ifindex 3
        wdev 0x1
        addr e4:5f:01:f8:f7:49
        type managed
        channel 1 (2412 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2412 MHz
        txpower 31.00 dBm
```

Then i type

```
wpa_cli
```

then

```
p2p_find
```

```
p2p_peers
```

However, it's cannot show other pi mac address.

Is anyone know to solve it.
or is there any way to do p2p?
Can anyone help me or provide useful methods